# remote api Error-10061 after upgrade to gae 1.7.6

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

After switching to gae 1.7.6 the remote_api does not work anymore.
1.7.5 worked fine.

### app.yaml

handlers:
- url: /rugad_remote.*
  #script: google.appengine.ext.remote_api.handler.application #1.7.5
  script: google.appengine.ext.remote_api.handler.app   #1.7.6
  login: admin

### rugadweb.py

```
HOST = '127.0.0.1:8080'      #test  
#HOST = 'xxx.appspot.com'    #prod  

def auth_func():
    return None, None             #test
    #return 'xxxxx', 'yyyyyyyy'   #prod

remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteApi(None, '/rugad_remote', auth_func, HOST)   #1.7.6
#remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteDatastore(None, '/rugad_remote', auth_func, HOST) #1.7.5
```

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\rugad\rugadweb.py", line 28, in 
        remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteApi(None, '/rugad_remote', auth_func, HOST)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\remo
    te_api\remote_api_stub.py", line 725, in ConfigureRemoteApi
        app_id = GetRemoteAppIdFromServer(server, path, rtok)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\remo
    te_api\remote_api_stub.py", line 568, in GetRemoteAppIdFromServer
        response = server.Send(path, payload=None, **urlargs)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\ap
    pengine_rpc.py", line 393, in Send
        f = self.opener.open(req)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 394, in open
        response = self._open(req, data)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 412, in _open
        '_open', req)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 372, in _call_chain
        result = func(*args)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1199, in http_open
        return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1174, in do_open
        raise URLError(err)
    urllib2.URLError: urlopen error [Errno 10061] Es konnte keine Verbindung herges
    tellt werden, da der Zielcomputer die Verbindung verweigerte
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same problem.
I fixed it using "localhost:8080" instead of "127.0.0.1:8080" and using an email adress for the login.

```
HOST = 'localhost:8080'

def auth_func():
    return "user@example.com", "password"

remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteApi(None, '/rugad_remote', auth_func, HOST)
```